# TypeScript update not reflecting on JavaScript (blank)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, transpiler

I am new to TypeScript and JavaScript. Yesterday I tried transpiling a typescript(ts) file into a javascript(js) file, there is no error showing anywhere, but the js file is just blank.  Did anyone also encounter this before or have any insight about this? Thank you!

[image: What shows on my VS Code - ts file:]

[image: How the .js file look:]

Please see below for the versions of development tools I use.

Thank you in advance!

Versions:

```
    theresa@xuans-air test % nvm --version
    0.35.0
    theresa@xuans-air test % npm -version
    7.24.0
    theresa@xuans-air test % node --version
    v16.10.0
    theresa@xuans-air test % tsc --version
    Version 4.8.4
    theresa@xuans-air ~ % code --help
    Visual Studio Code 1.73.0
```

About my computer and OS:
macOS
MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
Chip: Apple M1

On my .zshrc file:
#Homebrew

```
   export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
   export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
   source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

#NVM

```
   export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm     bash_completion
```

I tried reinstalling everything and removed the ## NVM part from my .zshrc file, but none seemed work.

Comment: It appears that you haven't saved your ts file. press ctrl+s and save it first/

Answer (score 0):

If you'll try to save this file it'll say

[image]

You can't see how the file changes on disk if it's not saved

Comment: ~~also use `tsx` its better then compiling ts to run it~~